# How does the browser render Images with different sizes (<img> tag in HTML)?

Tags: html, image, browser

If an HTML document has three images in different sizes (**5MB**, **50KB** and **10MB**) then which image will be rendered first in the page? Does the browser process `<img>` tags synchronously? That is, will the render sequence  be

**5_mb_img.jpg** > **50_kb_img.jpg** > **10_mb_img.jpg**

OR

might **50_kb_img.jpg** be rendered first because  it is smallest in size?

```
<img src="5_mb_img.jpg" /> <!-- a 5MB image file -->
<img src="50_kb_img.jpg" /> <!-- a 50KB image file -->
<img src="10_mb_img.jpg" /> <!-- a 10MB image file -->
```

**WHY A BOUNTY?** I know the answer but am expecting a very good explanation that helps someone who is searching it in Stack Overflow

Comment: Fetching is async. Rendering... probably implementation dependent. The first one to render ? It depends. If 10MB image is cached but 50KB is served with no-cache from a server that takes 15minutes to send it through an 28kbps connection, then 10MB will be rendered before 50KB.

Comment: @Kaiido: Good explanation

Comment: Please specify for which web browser you would an answer?

Comment: @ASTEFANI I was expecting a generalized answer.

Comment: As I see in your question : "Does the browser process [...] ? ", in my opinion it is impossible to generalized  because the loading procedure depend finally on on how the webbrowser interpreter engine works ...

Comment: But if we don't take care about how browser engine works @evilReiko already list all factors !

Comment: @ASTEFANI: yes, evailReiko answer is the best so far and most probably will got bounty. Also your answer is informative. upvoted

Comment: While this question is downvoted by some users, from the answers we can notice that some developers have the idea of "smaller images always render first", which makes this question reasonable to be upvoted!

Comment: @evilReiko: I agree with you. I have learned lot of things from here even I have more than 5 years of professional development experience. I am confused why **DOWN VOTERS** dislike that without leaving a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many factors to depend on.

Normally, the smallest will render first and the largest will render last.

- **Asynchronized Requests**: meaning you don't know which request happen first. When you have a huge HTML page, the first `<img src="...">` the browser sees will be requested first, while the last one will be requested last. But which request will get response first depend on other factors.
- **Server Response Time**: `<img src="http://domain1.com/img.jpg">` and `<img src="http://domain2.com/img.jpg">` are at different servers, one server could be really fast responding, while another could be really slow.
- **Image Size**: File size makes a difference.
- **Cache** (as Kaiido said): If an image is cached, most likely will be rendered before others. There is server cache and client (browser) cache, each play a role.
- **Client Speed Connection**: Your internet speed connection. If you have fiber-optic speed connection to request a small image, and have a cached giant image, there is a chance the requested image from server may render even before the cached.
- **Timeout**: If an image request times out, it may take few seconds 'til it times out, which means the bigger images may render will the small image still waiting until it times out.
- **Rendering Time**: Rendering 50MB may take seconds/minutes, while requesting and rendering a small image may take a split of a second. Rendering time depends on the client's computer specs.
- **Image Sprites**: When optimizing images for website, combining multiple images into one, may endup in a bigger image size but less requests. But most of the time it's better for faster rendering. [Read more.](https://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/)
- **Browsers Limit**: In the old days, IE6 had a limit of 2 requests only, which means the ones requested first even if huge will be loaded first and the others will have to wait. Now the limit has gone up. **EDIT**: as "A STEFANI" mentioned, each browser engine handles the DOM differently, which may affect the rendering.
- **Utilizing CDNs**: Requesting many images from one server even if small images, and requesting only 1 image from another server, makes a difference. The one getting many requests will have to do more processing causing the server to delay at responding.

Comment: Browser engine html interpretation could be added to the "Browsers Limit", no ?

Comment: @ASTEFANI correct, forgot about that. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, data are interpreted on the client side by the webbrowser engine.

Assuming that, the **render procedure** will **depend** on **which browser engine client is using** and most especially how engine treat content loading (priority stack for HTML,CSS, IMG ) ...

Most of webbrowsers, download the complete html first, then load css and js content, and when all of this are fully downloaded,  it start to request to download ressource - images in your case - (in linear mode) from the top of the page and render it asynchronously <=> when each element download is starting.

But some of modern webbrowser (in order to increase page load speed) may *set an higher priority for downloading&render the visible part of the html page.*

Theorically the HTML page loading is linear until you manually specify (via lazy load library or any other way like JS img preload or CSS img preload) a specific order.

Please note also that downloading & rendering page content elements is most of the time done by multithreading and/or multiproccessing to increase the loading speed.

To conlude, **if you want to masterize image load**, you have to **constraint the  start and** also the **rendering** of images ressource **by JS or CSS**.

Answer (score 0):

- The browser don't know the file size before it start download ;-)
- So usaly a browser loads the file in the order of the source code. But files like background image that the browser don't need to render loads later.
- Depending of the browser it load up to 8-10 files at the same time. The maximium was limited during the Mellisa virus in the 80'ies to limited DOD from one maschine. Today with Https2 more request are possible (and still file push)
- If you wan't swicth the files size depending on the screen resolution use srcset.
- Main context is the browser loads the files first that he need to render the screen, like css files, sync .js with write comand etc. So if you add the witdh and height attribute to your img tag the browser can calculate the Rendering without loading the image. It will first load other file that the he need to render.

Answer (score 0):

Q: If a HTML document has three images in different size (5MB, 50KB and 10MB) then which image will be rendered first in the page. Is browser process  tag synchronously?

A: The image with the less weight(MB or KB) will be the one to load first. As the higher the resolution, the more pixels will have to load on that particular image making it a little bit slower than the other with less resolution.

Answer (score 0):

The 50KB one will render first as it is the smallest file size there and will load first and therefore get more time to render.

Answer (score -3):

**Browser render Images small to larger.**